# conformal map $\{ Re(z) > 0 : |z-1|>1 \}$ onto unit disk

Tags: complex-analysis, conformal-geometry, mobius-transformation

How many conformal mapping we apply to map the exterior of the disk $\{z : |z-1|>1 \}$ in the right half plane to the unit disk?

Comment: The upper half-plane is $\operatorname{Im}(z)>0$, not $\operatorname{Re}(z)>0$... and what have you tried?

Comment: @ParclyTaxel, you are right, I mean right half plane. I know there is a map takes right plane to the unit disk and  there is a map takes  exterior of the unit disk to unit disk, but not sure how to use these maps to take exterior half disk to unit disk?